# meteorjs when running on android-device im getting this error

Tags: java, android, meteor, vue.js

I am trying to develop an app from meteor.js. I am able to compile and run on Apple devices. But when I try to run on android (meteor run android-device) I get the below error message from terminal. I have tried googling the issue but still could not get a fix!.

```js
Status of the individual requirements:        
✓ Java JDK                                    
✓ Android SDK                                 
✗ Android target: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
  at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
  at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
  at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
  at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
  at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
  ... 5 more
✓ Gradle
```

Comment: Does https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9510 help?

Comment: i had to install the correct version of android studio with its tools. its fixed. thanks

Comment: @SamaahRasheed please describe how you solved it in an _answer_ to your question, so that people who might face the same issue as you in the future can solve it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
meteor remove-platform android
```

As mentioned by @SamaahRasheed I then went to Android Studio and updated it:

> Android Studio > Check for updates

and then also updated everything else Android Studio then recommended I update as well.

Then I made sure JAVA_HOME was at least java 8

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then I re-added android platform:

```
meteor add-platform android
```

It may be that one of these was more important than the others, but this worked.